# IntelliJ inspections, clarification needed

Tags: intellij-idea

It appears that `IntelliJ 12 Ultimate` is missing some inspections relative what was present in `Community 11`

[image]
[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Inspections are provided by the plug-ins, make sure you didn't disable them in `Preferences` | `Plugins`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit for answering this question goes to [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder).

It appears, that by default, `Settings-> Plugins->Inspection Gadgets` are not enabled.

[image]

Enabling them put this and many other inspections into the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in IntelliJ 12 Ultimate by:

1. Click on Configure
2. Click Settings
3. Type "Serail" in the search box

[image]

Here is where to find Configure(Start up menu):
[image]

Comment: It seems that it's partially here, but a some things are missing

Comment: After you click on Configure, Click on Settings. On the settings page there is a search box at the top left. Or you can select "Inspections" from the template project settings.

Comment: Yes, take a look at my screenshot above. This is exactly what i did :)

Comment: Am not sure what to tell you. It's working on Windows. I do not have a Mac to test it on